# How can I center align the list horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have this site: [LINK](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/?product_category=test)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="portfolio">
    <li class="item item-cat photo1 photo mix_all" style="display: inline-block;  opacity: 1;"></li>
    <li class="item item-cat photo1 photo mix_all" style="display: inline-block;  opacity: 1;">// SOME CODE HTML</li>
    <li class="item item-cat photo1 photo mix_all" style="display: inline-block;  opacity: 1;">// SOME CODE HTML</li>
    <li class="item item-cat photo1 photo mix_all" style="display: inline-block;  opacity: 1;">// SOME CODE HTML</li>
    <li class="item item-cat photo1 photo mix_all" style="display: inline-block;  opacity: 1;">// SOME CODE HTML</li>
    <li class="item item-cat photo1 photo mix_all" style="display: inline-block;  opacity: 1;">// SOME CODE HTML</li>
    <li class="item item-cat photo1 photo mix_all" style="display: inline-block;  opacity: 1;">// SOME CODE HTML</li>     
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (max-width:770px) {
  .item-cat{width:100% !important;}
}

.item-cat {
  width:25%;
  max-width:360px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
```

I put a picture to understand what I want to do.

[image]

How can align the center this list?
I try to add `text-align: center` or `margin: 0 auto` but unfortunately it does not work.

Can you tell me please how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please don't link the code from your personnal website as it is dangerous because we don't know if it contains pishing links or viruses. Always prefer creating an excerpt of your issue with [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example.

Comment: margin doesn't affect on floated elements. #portfolio {text-align: center;} .item-cat { remove float: left}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use flexbox. This is an example :

```css
#container{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: grey;
 flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container > div{
    display:block;
    background-color:blue;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h9Ly1fc4/1/

You can check Browser Compatibility for the flexbox here:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: please, note, flexbox will not work in IE9 and lower (in case you have to maintain these)

Answer (score 1):

For block to center, you need to give it not only `margin` but also `width`. Add this to your css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:770px)
    #portfolio {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 360px;
    }
}
```

Width is by the width of image in a `li` element.

Comment: What if #portfolio must be fluid-width?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left;` and set the parent or container div to `text-align:center;`

```css
img{
  width:200px;
}

body{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/scc80.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to adjust the styles in your media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width:770px){
  .item-cat {
    width: 100%;
    float: none; /*remove the float*/
    display: block; /*set to display block, for centering*/
    margin: 0px auto; /*center using margin*/
  }
}
```